# How do I get rid of this overflowed pixels error in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, render, appbar

I have a navigationbar in flutter web and I am getting a render issue.  It works fine when I am full screen, but It shows the error once I minimized the page to almost mobile version.

This is my code:

'''

```
 class NavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavigationBar({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NavigationBarState createState() => _NavigationBarState();
}

class _NavigationBarState extends State<NavigationBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 20, 0),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      color: kNavBarBlueBackground,
      height: 100,
      child: Flexible(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            SizedBox(width: 20),
            Image.asset('assets/img/image_logo.png'),
            Spacer(),
            Row(
              children: [
                _NavBarItem('Inicio'),
                SizedBox(width: 35),
                _NavBarItem('Agencias'),
```

'''

This is the error I am getting.

[image]

Edited this with more code because user below asked for code where this navigation bar was placed in code:

'''

```
lass _ViajeroExpresoPageState extends State<ViajeroExpresoPage> {
  void openDrawer() {
    _drawerKey.currentState.openDrawer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ResponsiveBuilder(
      builder: (context, sizingInformation) {
        // Check the sizing information here and return your UI
        if (sizingInformation.deviceScreenType == DeviceScreenType.desktop) {
          return Desktop();
        }

        if (sizingInformation.deviceScreenType == DeviceScreenType.tablet) {
          return Mobile(openDrawer: openDrawer);
        }

        return Mobile(openDrawer: openDrawer);
      },
    );
  }
}

class Desktop extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function openDrawer;

  const Desktop({Key key, this.openDrawer}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _drawerKey,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          ListView(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: NavigationBar(),
              ),
```

'''

Comment: provide a code where your are using this navigation bar

Comment: @MehranUllah Hey Mehran I just edited the code.  let me know if that helps.  I believe it is something to do with the size of text, i believe i need to automate the text size so the buttons dont bump into each other when i minimize the width of the screen

Comment: Instead of `Row`, try `Wrap`.

Comment: still nothing,I also tried main axis alignment.space around, nothing

Comment: @user2827326 What you want to achieve with this code? simply explain in a comment I will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping the listview widget in 'expanded' widget

Comment: Still nothing :(

Comment: The issue is in the navigation bar.  Everything else is fine